# Having image in netbeans JavaDB database or SqlLite

Tags: java, database, jdbc, cachedrowset

How can insert and retreive an image in netbeans javaDB database (the one used under services tab/ Or SqlLite). What type will the attribute type be? and how can I get it using CachedRowSet?

In case this is needed
JavaDB installation: glassfish-3.1.2.2\javadb
JavaDB location : .netbeans-derby

Comment: You _can_ store an image (or any file) in a database as a `Blob` - binary data. I would suggest that you do not do this. Store it in a file and store the location of the file in the database. Storing large data fields in a database will make everything slower. If you are using sqlLite there is **very** little point in storing the image in there as it is a file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SqlLite you can not insert a new image into the database using java.
It's read only.you can insert image into the database using by database. Not from the java.
If you not have to insert image into database means you go for SqlLite..